# Puppeteer - how to navigate heavily javascript[ed] webpages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I wish to use puppeteer to navigate a heavily *scripted* website. I have tried the following snippet but it will fail due to timeout in loading one of the subsequent webpage.

I have also tried to include this parameter 
 {waitUntil:networkidle0/networkidle2/load/domcontentloaded } 
in the page.goto() but without success.

The site has a lot of advertisement scripts running in *background*. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks.

```
async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 2000 });
  page.on('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!', page.url()));
  //Goto website home page
  await page.goto('https://www.discuss.com.hk');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis1.png' });
  //goto another page in the website
  await page.goto('http://www.discuss.com.hk/forumdisplay.php?fid=215');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis2.png' });
  //Goto another page in the website
  await page.goto('http://www.discuss.com.hk/forumdisplay.php?fid=1192');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis3.png' });
  //Goto  another page in the website
  await page.goto('http://www.discuss.com.hk/viewthread.php?tid=27173245&extra=page%3D1');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis4.png' });
  await browser.close();
  return 'done!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting for something to come back first. My rule of thumb is every time I ask for a new resource (click a button, goto a url) I always perform a `waitForSelector`, in your case you could use.

```
await page.waitForSelector('#footer');
```

This following script works and creates 3 png files:-

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: false //true
    }); 

    const page = await browser.newPage(); 
    await page.setViewport({ width:1280, height:2000});

    await page.goto('https://www.discuss.com.hk');
    await page.waitForSelector('#footer');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis1.png' });

    await page.goto('http://www.discuss.com.hk/forumdisplay.php?fid=215');
    await page.waitForSelector('#footer');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis2.png' });

    await page.goto('http://www.discuss.com.hk/forumdisplay.php?fid=1192');
    await page.waitForSelector('#footer');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'dis3.png' });

    await browser.close(); 
}; 

run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But it doesn't work on my environment. I run this under an Linux container. So I can't use `{headless:false}`.

Comment: I should clarify by saying the script would succeed some of the time. Let say  1 in 4 when I try it on my cloud development environment. I am not sure whether this is related to the environment.

Comment: You can test aspects of your script here if you want to see what the container is doing https://chrome.browserless.io/. This is an interactive debugger that displays your site + has devtools accessible and is run on a linux container

Comment: @griffith_joel, how does it work? The tip says `console.log` will print to debug window. But even I just have a single statement `console.log('one two three')` and then by pressing the **green play** button. There is nothing to see.

Comment: I apologize, that debugger went down, try again now!

Comment: Great, your tool does help to trouble shoot my problem! I guess the **timeout** issue is caused by `document.write` the site is using. But no idea how to get around it